# Error when Publishing Web Application on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, web

I have created a web application and it is working very good on visual studio development server, but when I change the server to be Local IIS Web server i got the following error

> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location:
>   http://localhost/Dadas.Website/Default.aspx Line Number 1, Column 1:

I don't know what is the problem, please if you can help I will be thankful

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you map your app to a virtual directory on IIS?

Comment: Yes, when I choose it I click create virtual directory and I got a message that it is created successfully.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303066/what-could-be-causing-an-xml-parsing-error-no-element-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Rick's blog post [Test your ASP.NET MVC or WebForms Application on IIS 7 in 30 seconds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx), which covers the common issues that people hit when coverting their Web apps to run on IIS.

Key quote from the post: "IIS cannot run an ASP.NET project that has been created in the default Visual Studio project folder (C:\users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects). Select a folder where IIS can access the files, such as C:\Webs."

Another useful reference is the [Application Pool Identities](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/) article on IIS.net. See the Securing Resources section for information on how to give the IIS AppPoolIdentity permissions to a folder.