# XML Parsing Error: no element found while working in localhost

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I am facing one weird problem in my project. Before sometimes it was running fine on the local and on the server, but after I have added one new page in my project and then it had stopped working. still the admin panel inside the same project but in different folder is working fine. but not sure, y this front end pages have stopped working.

[image]

Here I have attached the snapshot for the error I am getting after adding the new page. Please help me if anybody knows about this problem.

Thanks

this is the error I am getting -

XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://localhost:3989/Colex/home.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:

Hey whenever I comment my connection string in web.config its runs perfectly, can anybody tell me whats wrong in this connectionstring.

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="sqlconstr" connectionString="data source=ashton;database=colex;user id=sa;pwd=sa123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Can you provide the source code to '/Colex/home.aspx'?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide whatever information didn't make it in. There's nothing here that's even close to answerable. Thanks. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303066/what-could-be-causing-an-xml-parsing-error-no-element-found it may be help you

Comment: What happens when you run with a debugger attached? Any exceptions in your code? Is your page returning a content type of `application/xml`?