# The name 'Textbox1' does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im receiving this error The name 'Textbox1' does not exist in the current context when i try to do this

```
<script runat="server">
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 string connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TDBSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

string query = "SELECT news, news_date FROM [IBSI].[dbo].[ibsi.news]";

if (query != null)
{
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
  {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {

      conn.Open();
      SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      if (rdr.HasRows)
      {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {

          Textbox1.Text=rdr["news"].ToString() ;


        }
      }
    }
  }
}
else 
{
  Response.Write("<p>No customer selected</p>"); 
}
Response.End();
}
</script>
```

The textbox1 is existing

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="168px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                            Width="303px"></asp:TextBox>
```

What could be wrong in my code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TextBox1 is not the same as Textbox1. Try with a B instead of b, so your code should be:

```
...
        while (rdr.Read())
        {

          TextBox1.Text=rdr["news"].ToString() ;


        }
...
```

Comment: oh your right but now im receiving this error XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://localhost:50320/WebSite/IBSI.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:

Comment: there might be plenty of reasons for that error, you can follow some suggestions from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303066/what-could-be-causing-an-xml-parsing-error-no-element-found